# using Grep or Sed to get a text beetween {}

Tags: bash, sed, grep

first thread on Stack Overflow,

I'm learning bash and i can't figure how to use Grep or Sed to a specific used. i want to extract/print all the data beetween specific characters like { and } or [ and ].
I've search a lot, but i can't find anything related to get something if the two characters are not on the same line.
I hope you can help me !
Thanks in advance

Comment: ah.. "not on the same line". This is why we ask that you include a small set of sample input, the expected output from that input, your best solution to solving the problem with code, it's current output and/or error messages and your thoughts about why it should work. Realize that *nix (Linux/Unix) utilities generally want to process 1 line of data at a time, so what you're asking for will take some extra work. Did you go thru the [sed tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) ? You may find what you need there, but this is an advanced problem in any *nix tool.

Comment: If you decide to update your Q, please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as `code/data/output/errorMsgs`. For more info see  [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Comment: I don't think this is a task for `sed` or `grep`.

Comment: No sample input, no expected output, no attempt at a solution and yet this Q has 6 answers so far! Baffling... @sebWhatever - see [ask] for how to ask a question.

Comment: @EdMorton and it has created a good amount of confusion between contributors. voting to close.

Comment: @PesaThe - `grep` is "the" tool designed specifically for such task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize that OP has `{` and `}` in two separate lines. `sed` would be easier,

```
 $ sed -n '/{/,/}/{//!p}' inputfile
```

For square brackets, you have to escape the characters:

```
 $ sed -n '/\[/,/\]/{//!p}' inputfile
```

inputfile:

```
$ cat inputfile
Some text inside
{
between braces
}
some other text

[
between square bracket
]

some more text
```

output:

```
$ sed -n '/{/,/}/{//!p}' inputfile
between braces

$ sed -n '/\[/,/\]/{//!p}' inputfile
between square bracket
```

If they are on the same line, use `perl-style-regex` in `grep`  and option `-o`:

```
 $ echo 'Some text {between}'  | grep -o -P '(?<=\{).*(?=\})' 
 between

 $ echo 'Some text [between]'  | grep -o -P '(?<=\[).*(?=\])' 
 between
```

Comment: `echo -e 'aa{bb\ncc\ndd}ee'|sed -n '/{/,/}/{//!p}'` would output `cc` only, I guess that's NOT what @sebXIII1 been asking for

Comment: No, but you would use `grep` for this, which I have shown in my answer. `echo 'aa{bb\ncc\ndd}ee' | grep -o -P '(?<=\{).*(?=\})'`. or put the output of `echo` into a file and use `sed`.

Comment: iamauser, the `echo -e 'aa{bb\ncc\ndd}ee'|grep -o -P '(?<=\{).*(?=\})'` does NOT work either...

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed for the `{}` case like this

```
sed 's!.*{\(.*\)}.*!\1!'
```

`\1` is a 'Remember pattern' that remembers everything that is within (.*)

Answer (score 0):

With modern `grep` (2.6.3+) - it's easy:

```
[root@s]$ cat test
aa{bb]
cc}dd [ee] ff [gg
hh] ii {jj} kk
[root@s]$ <test grep -z -P '({[^}]+}|\[[^]]+\])' -o
{bb]
cc}
[ee]
[gg
hh]
{jj}
```

If Your `grep` is 2.5.1 or lower (where `-z` didn't exist and `-P` was poorly-implemented) - the input needs to be converted to 1-line first.
Example: `tr '\n' '\t'` replaces all new-lines with tab-characters (if desired - opposite replacement can be done after processing).

[image: how it shows in color]

```
[root@s]$ <test tr '\n' '\t'|grep '\(\[[^]]*\]\|{[^}]*}\)' --color=always|tr '\t' '\n'
aa{bb]
cc}dd [ee] ff [gg
hh] ii {jj} kk

[root@s]$ <test tr '\n' '\t'|grep '\(\[[^]]*\]\|{[^}]*}\)' -o
{bb]    cc}
[ee]
[gg     hh]
{jj}
```

For both versions You can choose which presentation (`-o` or `--color=always`) is more appealing.

P.S. all of the above assumes there's no nesting/escaping of those { } [ ] characters in the input

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed but it's better with awk

```
sed '
/{/!d
s/[^{]*//
:A
$bB
N
/}/!bA
:B
s/}[^}]*$/}/
t
d
' infile
```

Comment: `echo 'aa {bb} cc {dd} ee'|sed '...yoursolutionhere...'` outputs `{bb} cc {dd}`, it definitely IS possible to do it properly with `sed`, just a regular `grep` and `awk` would be much more elegant/straightforward here

Comment: You are right but the op ask for the two characters are not on the same line.